# Change content of server side div from Client side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have the following setup:

```
<div id="TotalAddressYears" runat="server">YEARS</div>

<asp:Button OnClick="btn_GetInfo" runat="server" Text="GET RESULTS" CausesValidation="false"/>

function btn_YearsSelected(select) 
{        
$('#<%=TotalAddressYears.ClientID %>').text("ALEXALQQQQQEX");
}

protected void btn_GetInfo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("TEXT: " + TotalAddressYears.InnerText);
    Response.End();
}
```

My intention is that when the JQuery updates the content of the `TotalAddressYears` div, this can be picked up on the server side, and will be shown in the `Response.Write`. But currently it does not, it prints out the original value.

Can this be done?

I know I can use AJAX to do this, but I do not want to do this as it does not fit in with the rest of my project.

I suspect it cannot, but maybe someone knows of a way it can be done?

EDIT:

My target is to get the `Response.Write` to print out `ALEXALQQQQQEX` after the user has triggered the JQuery function `btn_YearsSelected`

Comment: Sorry, Ajax is the way here. You seem to mix up client and server side execution. Server side code executes, finishes, sends complete page to the client, and then client code executes. They cannot interchange half way through

Comment: can you please show what you want to result ?

Comment: @Andrei I agree with what you are saying, except for that fact that the page can be rendered by the server side code, then the client can enter a value into the server side div, and when they submit the page, the updated value will reach the server, so is there not a way for me to plug into this functionality?

Comment: There is no logic of what you are trying to do... If i want to read the changed value server side, use a hidden field, change it's value in javascript and then when the form is posted to the server you can read the value from there.

Comment: @Alex, yeah, I see, that can be done indeed. However not with a plain div. You need to either use textbox, or maintain a hidden field - something got to post the value to the server, and div does not do it

Comment: @Andrei you and Esko both gave the correct answer, so if one of you would please write this as the answer then I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep client-side, Ajax is the only way to go. However if full page postback is ok for your scenario, then you can use something instead of the div, or together with it, to post the data to the server.

You could use TextBox instead of the div:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TotalAddressYears" ...
```

And then use it exactly as you did use div.

Or you could keep div and add a hidden field beside it:

```
<div id="TotalAddressYears" runat="server">YEARS</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="TotalAddressYearsHidden" ...>
```

Make sure to update both div and the field with new value, and then use hidden field on the server side to retrieve the value.